# fetch JSON data dynamically in NodeJS REST api

Tags: node.js, json, rest, express, node-fetch

I am trying to fetch JSON data from API. I am using node-fetch in my express app. I am able to fetch data if I enter the absolute URL. But I am looking to fetch data entered in req.body like this

```
app.post('/data', async(req, res) => {
  const url = req.body 
  const fetchData = await fetch(url)
  const data = await fetchData.json()
  res.json({data: data})
})
```

This is the error im getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`
Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

url = req.body returns object you need to create string URL and pass